# How long do I need to wait before sending additional requests to IIS

Tags: iis

I have a console app written specifically to time the request-response of calling a service. This is more for experimenting but nonetheless, we want to compare the response times of various ways of doing things.

The app can make two requests but subsequent requests timeout. The response is < 100ms, generally. I suspect the requests are being fired too quickly and IIS is throttling since it thinks it's a DOS attack (guessing). Stopping the console app and restarting is enough to allow additional two requests.

The server is another machine (not running on my machine) but inside our firewall.

Basically, the code below runs inside a FOR loop:

```
        long start = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL1);

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        long end = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

        long duration = end - start;

        Console.WriteLine("duration: " + duration);
```

If this is some protection built into IIS, how can I make a bunch of requests and perform an accurate analysis of the response times? Or, how do I temporarily disable this in IIS (but that's probably not recommended) ?

Answer (score 0):

Well I was curious, so I brought your code into Visual Studio, and sure enough - you're right. It worked fine when I was connecting to IIS Express locally (in another Visual Studio instance), but didn't work when I tried connecting to a real remote server running IIS 7.5.

The thing that didn't seem right, however, is that I could execute the console app, see it timeout after 2 requests, quickly close it and rerun it, and it would give me another 2 requests.  That made me think this wasn't a server issue, but rather something within .NET.  If it was actually a DOS prevention technique, you'd think it would timeout for a fixed amount of time.

So I tried this with a 3rd party HTTP component I've used in the past, specifically [Chilkat](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/) in this case, and it worked as expected.  I was able to send repeated requests to the remote server. I can't say exactly what's causing the problem, but the fix may be as easy as not using the built-in HttpWebRequest object.